# WCF endpoint will not register

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating this WCF but I have ran into this problem with the ABC of my WCF.

In my App.Config I have the following:

```
<service name="WCFService.AuctionService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IAuctionService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IArtPieceService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFService/AuctionService/"/>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFService/ArtPieceService/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

The above is the updated version of the app.config file.

Then it won't run.
It gives me an endpoint is not defined.
The Service is not found on the list of contracts.

The following is my classes:

```
 public class AuctionService : IAuctionService {
    private AuctionDb _ctr = new AuctionDb();

    public void Add(Auction auction) {
        String regName = "^[a - zA - Z0 - 9]{ 4,10}$";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(auction.AuctionName, regName) || auction.AuctionName.Length > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if(auction.LotDuration.TotalSeconds > 0 || auction.LotDuration.TotalMinutes > 120 || auction.Lots.Count > 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        _ctr.Add(auction);
    }

    public void Update(Auction auction) {
        String regName = "^[a - zA - Z0 - 9]{ 4,10}$";
        if (Regex.IsMatch(auction.AuctionName, regName) || auction.AuctionName.Length > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (auction.LotDuration.TotalSeconds > 0 || auction.LotDuration.TotalMinutes > 120 || auction.Lots.Count > 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        _ctr.Update(auction);
    }

    public List<Auction> GetAll() {
        return _ctr.GetAll();
    }
}

public class ArtPieceService : IArtPieceService
{
    public void Add(ArtPiece piece)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The following is my ServiceContracts:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IArtPieceService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Add(ArtPiece piece);
}
```

And the other Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuctionService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Add(Auction auction);
    [OperationContract]
    void Update(Auction auction);

    [OperationContract]
    List<Auction> GetAll();
}
```

I the ArtPieceService gives an endpoint not defined and the contract not found on the list of contracts.

Up front thanks for the help.

Comment: Two endpoints cannot have the same address

Comment: you can have only one endpoint defined per binding.

Comment: try using a different value on the `address` property of your two endpoints

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh are you sure on the one with only one endpoint pr binding?

Comment: Check update it is still not working

Comment: change the value of `address` property to something different that `" "` for second endpoint

Comment: Does your AuctionService class implement both IAuctionService and IArtPieceService interfaces? And are they (interfaces) both marked with [ServiceContract]?

Comment: Since you have two classes, you need to define two services in the xml config. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two endpoints cannot have the same address.

When you add the following endpoint, instead of using this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IArtPieceService"/>
```

Specify a new address like this:

```
<endpoint address="service2" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IArtPieceService"/>
```

This means that when you access the second endpoint, you need to use the following url:

```
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFService/AuctionService/service2
```

This of course assumes that your AuctionService class implements both the IAuctionService and IArtPieceService contracts (interfaces)

If you want to have two different classes for the two different services, then you have to create another `service` xml element in app.config.

This will result in you having two `service` elements as children in your `services` element.

This new element is a copy of the original element but with different name and different address and different contract. Like this:

```
<service name="WCFService.ArtPieceService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IArtPieceService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFService/ArtPieceService/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Also, make sure that you open a separate ServiceHost instances for the two services.

Comment: Just had to read this message with fresh eyes to realize it was worth gold ;) thanks for the help